# I use Robotframework extract number from Excel to Send Request API

Tags: python, excel, selenium, robotframework

I use Robotframework extract number  from Excel   to Send Request API  for a token  but Response is show "null" because when robot extract number it adds the back numbers automatically  How can I delete this

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwP2A.png)

Comment: please share an example of some code you are using/writing so that we can see how you do your steps and what libs you use. And what do you mean by "back numbers" ?

Answer (score 0):

ok now i can fix this  , This is  my code   . I use Keyword covert To Integer

```
   Open Excel    C:\\Users\\dawil\\Desktop\\TestNum.xls    default=True
${subNumb}=    Read Cell Data By Coordinates    Sheet1    0    0
${subNumb}=    Convert To Integer    ${subNumb}
Create Session    GetToken    https://digitaltest.dtac.co.th    verify=true
${response}=    Post Request    GetToken    uri=/mobileapi/auth/v1.0.0/auth/requestlogin?subrNumb=${subNumb}&chanelId=2100251114&device=iPhone10&uid=fee51bb2-f0d9-4654-9476-5154e964a196&brandModel=Apple&osVersion=11.3&appVersion=7.0&lang=TH&getProfile
${token}=    Get Json Value    ${response.text}    /data/token
${access_token}=    Remove String    ${token}    "
Put String To Cell    Sheet1    0    0    ${access_token}
Append To File    number.csv    ${access_token}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe your format in excel column is not "TEXT". You must format it's as text.
[image: Check this picture]

Comment: but if I change that format, It's help?  sorry I don't know much about using it.  This first time to write robot extract data from excel.

Comment: Yes if you change. but you can do convert to integer like your own answers